# Проверяемая кнопка

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpushbutton

Как мне сделать чтобы кнопка

```
    self.runBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    self.runBtn.setCheckable(True)
    self.runBtn.setText("Y")
    self.runBtn.setObjectName("runBtn")
    self.runBtn.clicked.connect(self.runProcess)
```

При повторном нажатии на неё (неактивна) вызывала метод

```
def hekke():
    print("hello")
```

То есть, когда переходит вручную из этого состояния

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и лучше объясните, что вы хотите сделать, а также ответьте на мое сообщение в предыдущем вашем вопросе.

Comment: Вот смотрите,
Когда ты нажимаешь на кнопку setChekable(True), то она вызывает метод. Но когда кликаешь на неё снова ничего не происходит

Comment: sorry, но вы плохо прочитали мой первый комментарий

Comment: @S.Nick , Я правил,  возможно я вас понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, правильно ли я вас понял, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.runBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.runBtn.setCheckable(True)
        self.runBtn.setText("Y")
        self.runBtn.setObjectName("runBtn")
        self.runBtn.clicked.connect(self.runProcess)

    def runProcess(self, state):
        if state:
            print(f"Button Checked: {state}") 
        else:
            self.hekke()

    def hekke(self):
        print("Hello повторное нажатие.")                
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @seel  правильно ли я вас понял ?

Comment: так точно капитан)